# How to get the rows of a nested HTML table using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to get the table rows from a XHTML using XPath / XSLT. My sample xhtml looks like this :

```
<body>
<....>
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td/>
         <td/>
         <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <....>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

In the above structure, `<tbody>` may or may not be there. Tables could be nested to any level. Now I want get all the rows for a given table. So when I am processing the outer table, I want to get only the outer row (one that contains 3 tds) but not the inner tr (inside the nested table). How can I do this using XSLT or XPath?

Edit : What I am essentially looking for is a way of getting all descendant::y for a node x, but y should not be a descendant of **another** x. The path from x->y should not contain another x. I may not have anything that distinguishes the outer x from the inner x.

Note : I am trying to do this with many HTMLs which all have different structures, and I cannot change the structure of any HTML file - it is given to me. The only thing is that they are all well formed XHTML.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using an XML parser for html, even xhtml, is a bad idea.  Please provide some more context to the problem.

Comment: @mvrak Actually there are some quite good HTML parsers that use xpath (and an underlying XML parser such as libxml2).

Comment: @mvrak I am parsing the xhtml already for other reasons, not just for this problem. I am converting HTML to PDF and before doing so I need to modify the HTML in several ways - add header, footer, watermark etc. and parsing the HTML seems to the only way out. But just curious to know why you said it is a bad idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I am essentially looking for is a way of getting all
>   `descendant::y` for a node `x`, but `y` should not be a descendant of
>   another `x`.

**Suppose $n is the element named `x`. You want**:

```
$n//y[count(ancestor::x) = count($n/ancestor-or-self::x)]
```

This selects all `y` that are descendents of $n and that have such a number of `x` ancestors that is exactly one greater than the number of ancestor::x of $n.

Because `$n` contains an `x` element, this means that for all selected `y` the `x` contained in `$n` is their first `ancestor::x` .

For your practical purposes, you only have to substitute `$n` above with the exact XPath expression that selects the `x` element it contains.

Answer (score 2):

The following expression selects the `tr` elements of any `table` element that does not have a `table` as an ancestor (i.e. the outermost tables, only) and that may or may not have a `tbody` element:

```
//table[not(ancestor::table)]/tbody/tr|//table[not(ancestor::table)]/tr
```

This is the union of two separate expressions, one that selects the correct element when `tbody` is present and another for when it is not.

Comment: This would exclude the tables that are nested right ? May be I was not clear enough. I want to process all the tables. So table is the context node and I want to get all __its__ rows but not rows of a nested table (.//tr will not do). I can just use ./tbody/tr | ./tr as you have indicated. That will solve it for me. But I would really like to get a more generic solution if possible, without assuming tbody because I may need similar thing for <div>. In essence I am trying to get all decendent::y of a node x where y is not inside another x.  Any ideas ? Thanks for your help.